# receive comments from or by

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I would like some help in choosing the correct sentence between:

- A. I received comments from Person A
- B. I received comments by Person

Does it matter if the sentences alter to

- A. This paper benefits from comments and clarifications received by
  Person/Persons name/s
- B. This paper benefits from comments and clarifications received from
  Person/Persons name/s

Comment: The choice of preposition can **dramatically** alter the meaning of a sentence. This is the case here. We need to know who has received the comments and clarifications and what the sentence is supposed to mean. Please see the [prepositions tag help](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/prepositions/info).

Comment: Received from. Sent by, written by, made by, &etc...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's incomplete. The question needs to explain the intended meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A. I received comments from Person A
>
> B. I received comments by Person

Both are correct, although in the second case you could argue it gives a more indirect reception of comments (so the comments are *by* person A, but it wasn't necessarily person A who gave the comments to you).

> Does it matter if the sentences alter to

Yes, it matters, because now you're not saying *comments by* but rather *received by*. In example A it is the person/persons that are who received the comments. In example B, they are the ones making them.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE.This site strives to provide objective answers. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good answers. As it stands your answer is purely subjective.